# Image adapt to parent size, based upon device orientation

Tags: jquery, css, orientation, screen-orientation

I've got a simple feature that has struggling me for a longer time necessary. Hopefully you guys can assist.

I'm creating a page on a web-app that contains a map of an area. The image itself is landscape and therefor is bigger than the device when it's held portrait, knowing the image is fullscreen.

To adapt to the useable area on the device, I've set the parent to overflow scroll, so the user can drag the image to see the whole image. Sort of like Google Maps :)

Now my issue: I want the image to adapt to the orientation of the device. And on such way that if

- **The device is held portrait:** The image **height** is 100% equal to parent **height** and the horizontal axes is set to `overflow:scroll`, so you can't scroll up/downward, but can do sideways
- **The device is held landscape:** The image **width** is 100% equal to the parent **width** and the vertical axes is set to `overflow: scroll`, so you can scroll up/downward, but not sideways.

For that, I'm using the following jQuery:

```
// Map equal size to parent space
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
var docH = $(document).outerHeight(),
    docHPX = docH + 'px',
    docW = $(document).outerWidth(),
    docWPX = docW + 'px',
    navH = $('.nav').outerHeight() * 2,
    remH = docH - navH + 'px';
$('.plattegrond').css({
    'height': docHPX,
    'width': docWPX
});

if (docH > docW) {
    $('.plattegrond img').css({
        'height':           remH,
        'width':            "",
        'overflow-x':   'scroll',
        'overflow-y':   ""
    });
} else if (docW > docH) {
    $('.plattegrond img').css({
        'height':           "",
        'width':            docWPX,
        'overflow-x':   "",
        'overflow-y':   'scroll'
    });
};
});
```

Now, if you check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e754o93x/1/) you can mostly experience this idea.. Although the code isn't that correct. Especially if you change the fiddle orientation (move height/width guides) from landscape back to portrait. Everytime you move anything, the image size get's increased..

So I'm looking for a suitable solution for my wishes. Who o who can help? :)

Answer (score 1):

if you're using jQuery.mobile.js (which I'm 90% sure you are) then you can use the code below:

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function(){
    if(window.innerHeight<window.innerWidth){
        $('.plattegrond img').css({
            'width':$('.plattegrond').parent().width()+'px',
            'height':'auto',
            'overflow-x':'hidden',
            'overflow-y':'scroll'
        });
        }
    else{
        $('.plattegrond img').css({
            'height':$('.plattegrond').parent().height()+'px',
            'width':'auto',
            'overflow-x':'scroll',
            'overflow-y':'hidden'
        });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nope, no framework at all. The app itself is that easy, phone only that I'm creating it all myself, for small-size's sake. - Does that changes the situation? Your code however seems pretty suiting! - Although I don't see that much difference than my original code, except no variables.

Comment: jQuery.mobile.js is not a framework, it's just a small library specifically designed for mobile events (touch, slide, orientationchange and etc)

Comment: worth to mention that all the apps must and do use jQuery.mobile.js

Comment: Could you refer to a source that declares one should use jQuery.mobile.js? I've tested the app already on both iOS and android devices and they work perfectly. - I have never saw that rule though. I will test your code. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend testing your code with the JSfiddle. I've tested it both in my IDE and in JSfiddle and the image doesn't adapt when the orientation changes. And even if you don't do anything at all, then it's not 100% to either width or height (dep. on orientation) and the scrolling doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm sorry the "must" I've mentioned doesn't mean it's a rule, it's a "must" as in it's better to use it (for the sake of ease of read and edit and not reinventing the wheel)!

Comment: BTW the code wouldn't work in jsfiddle as it is written (optimized) for mobile devices only (must be checked in a mobile device). also if you wanna style it at the page load, you must do the whole "if" outside the event once.

Comment: For jQuery mobile thingy, I will read myself into it. Thank you. - Regarding the code. Hm, I will test it on a mobile device then. For the 'if' event, can't you simply use `$(window).on("load resize",function(e){` instead of `.bind("orientation change",` ?

Comment: sure you can use the `load` event, but the `resize` event wouldn't work on mobile devices, because you're not actually re-sizing, that's actually why they came up with `orientationchange` event

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could just use media queries since you are only changing the styles being applied to the elements:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
.plattegrond img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1024px) 
and (max-device-width : 768px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
.plattegrond img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Note that devices have different resolutions and recommend using (R)Em's instead of PX values. The idea of using media queries is quite smart, I think. Saves a few jQuery lines. CSS > jQuery *imho*. Thanks!